# Showing that $\sqrt{1+z} + \sqrt{1-z}$ is Analytic (Proof Verification)

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

> **Ahlfors**: Give a precise definition of a single-valued branch of the function $\sqrt{1+z} + \sqrt{1-z}$ in a suitable region, and prove that it is analytic.

Is my following proof attempt valid?

---

**Giving a precise definition of a single-valued branch of the function $\sqrt{1+z} +
 \sqrt{1-z}$:**

1. Let $\varOmega_+ = \mathbb{C} - (-\infty, -1]$ and observe that $\sqrt{1+z}$ is a well-defined single-valued function on $\varOmega_+$ (open and connected) if we choose the branch of the original function with positive real part.
2. And again if we let $\varOmega_- = \mathbb{C} - (1, \infty]$ we can observe that for similar reasons $\sqrt{1-z}$ is a well-defined single-valued function on $\varOmega_-$ (open and connected) if we choose the branch of the original function with positive real part.
3. Now let $\varOmega$ denote $\mathbb{C} - \left( (-\infty, -1] \cup [1, \infty) \right)$ and let $f = \sqrt{1+z} + \sqrt{1-z}$ s.t. $\sqrt{1+z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$ are the single-valued functions as defined above.  We now have that $f$ is a well-defined function on $\varOmega$ (where $\varOmega$ is open and connected in $\mathbb{C}$).

---

**Showing that $\sqrt{1+z} + \sqrt{1-z}$ is Analytic:**

1. We have that the sum of two analytic functions is itself analytic (since the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives).  Hence if we can show that both $\sqrt{1+z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$ are analytic, then $f = \sqrt{1+z} + \sqrt{1-z}$ will also be analytic.
2. We take it for granted that the individual (single-valued) functions $\sqrt{1+z}$ and $\sqrt{1-z}$ are continuous.
3. We now show that $\sqrt{1+z}$ is analytic.  Consider $\sqrt{1+z}$'s inverse function is $z = w^2 - 1 = (\sqrt{w+1})^{-1}$.
4. Then using notation from calculus we have that $\Delta z \rightarrow  0$ implies that $\Delta w \rightarrow 0$. We then have
   $$
   \lim_{\Delta z \to 0} {\Delta w \over \Delta z} = \lim_{\Delta w \to 0} {\Delta w \over \Delta z}
   $$

   so that

   $$
   {dw \over dz} = {1 \over {dz \over dw}} = {1 \over 2w} = {1 \over 2 \sqrt{1+z}}
   $$
5. We now show that $\sqrt{1-z}$ is analytic.  Consider $\sqrt{1-z}$'s inverse function is $z = -w^2 - 1 = (\sqrt{w-1})^{-1}$.
6. Then, as above, we have that $\Delta z \rightarrow  0$ implies that $\Delta w \rightarrow 0$.

   so that

   $$
   {dw \over dz} = {1 \over {dz \over dw}} = {1 \over -2w} = -{1 \over 2 \sqrt{1-z}}
   $$
7. Then in case $f(z) = \sqrt{1+z} + \sqrt{1-z}$, we have that ${dw \over dz} = {1 \over 2 \sqrt{1+z}} - {1 \over 2 \sqrt{1-z}}$ and hence $\sqrt{1+z} + \sqrt{1-z}$ is analytic as desired.

Comment: What is it, $\sqrt{1-z}$, as you wrote in the quote, or $\sqrt{z-1}$, as you wrote in the title?

Comment: Excellent point!  I had to redo the problem above.  It's now consistent.

Comment: You forgot the title ;) Let me see if your work is correct.

Comment: "branch of the original function" <- Is that a literal translation from (whatever your native language is)? The English name is "square root function" (the "square" can sometimes be omitted).

Comment: By "branch" I mean "value (of the function)".  It's a term used by Ahlfors that I think might be somewhat archaic nowadays.  My native language is English.

Comment: "branch" is correct, I meant the word "original". "root" has meanings related to "original" outside of mathematics.

Comment: Oh I see.  No I mean "original" as "the original function we were talking about", not as a synonym for "root".  But I see how that is confusing as written.

Comment: In point 2. of the definition, you have a typo, $\mathbb{C}-(1,\infty]$ ought to be $\mathbb{C}-[1,\infty)$ (it's correctly typed later). In point 2. of the second part, "taking it for granted" that the functions are continuous is perhaps not adequate. Anyway, it may be better to treat both as the composition of the principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$ with an affine linear function than separately. Your notation $z=w^2-1=(\sqrt{w+1})^{-1}$ is incorrect. If you want to have a ${}^{-1}$, give them a name and write e.g. $f_1^{-1}(w)$. In point 5., $z=-w^2+1$, not $-w^2-1$. But altogether not bad.